# Error when Trying to Execute GraphQL Mutation with Micronaut and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, graphql, micronaut

I am creating a microanuat and kotlin app using grapqhl but when trying with curl am
getting an error which i have pasted below the code, am trying to figure wher i am going wrong

```
    import graphql.ExecutionInput
    import graphql.GraphQL
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
    import io.micron    " curl -X POST   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{
            "query": "mutation {
              createItem(name: \"New Item\", description: \"Description of the new item\") {
                id
                name
                description
              }
            }"
          }'   http://localhost:8080/graphql
        {"_links":{"self":[{"href":"/graphql","templated":false}]},"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Method [POST] not allowed for URI [/graphql]. Allowed methods: [HEAD, GET]"}]},"message":"Method Not Allowed"}aut.http.annotation.Post
    import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
    
    @Controller("/graphql")
    class GraphQLController(private val graphQL: GraphQL) {
    
        @Post
        fun executeQuery(request: HttpRequest<String>): Any {
            val executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                    .query(request.body.orElse(""))
                    .build()
    
            return graphQL.execute(executionInput)
        }
    }
    
        import graphql.GraphQL
    import graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema
    import javax.inject.Singleton
    
    @Singleton
    class GraphQLConfiguration(private val graphQLSchema: GraphQLSchema) {
        @Singleton
        fun graphQL(): GraphQL {
            return GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build()
        }
    }
    
        type Item {
      id: ID!
      name: String!
      description: String
    }
    
    type Query {
      getAllItems: [Item]
      getItemById(id: ID!): Item
    }
    
    type Mutation {
      createItem(name: String!, description: String): Item
      updateItem(id: ID!, name: String!, description: String): Item
      deleteItem(id: ID!): Boolean
    }
    @Singleton
    @Transactional
    class ItemGraphQL(private val itemRepository: ItemRepository) : GraphQLQueryResolver, GraphQLMutationResolver {
    
        @ReadOnly
        fun getAllItems(): List<Item> {
            return itemRepository.findAll()
        }
    
        @ReadOnly
        fun getItemById(id: Long): Item? {
            return itemRepository.findById(id).orElse(null)
        }
    
        fun createItem(name: String, description: String): Item {
            val item = Item(name = name, description = description)
            return itemRepository.save(item)
        }
    
        fun updateItem(id: Long, name: String, description: String): Item {
            val item = itemRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow { NoSuchElementException("Item not found") }
            item.name = name
            item.description = description
            return itemRepository.update(item)
        }
    
        fun deleteItem(id: Long): Boolean {
            itemRepository.deleteById(id)
            return true
        }
    }
```

{"_links":{"self":[{"href":"/graphql","templated":false}]},"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [graphQL] of class: shoprite.moneymarket.GraphQLController\n\nMessage: No bean of type [graphql.GraphQL] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).\nPath Taken: new GraphQLController(GraphQL graphQL) --> new GraphQLController([GraphQL graphQL])"}]},"message":"Internal Server Error"}